# Having Problems with a map generation script for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my class, we are using unity to create a game. I made a script to take a text field and generate a map based on the text field. It generates correctly except for the very last "tile". The code looks like this. (all the public variables have models inside unity)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MakeFloorPlan : MonoBehaviour {
[TextArea(40,40)]
public string map = 
    "________\n" +
    "________\n" +
    "________\n" +
    "________\n" +
    "________\n" +
    "________\n" +
    "________\n" +
    "________\n";
public GameObject doorV;
public GameObject doorH;
public GameObject floor;
public GameObject wallLeft;
public GameObject wallRight;
public GameObject wallUp;
public GameObject wallDown; 
public GameObject wallFloor;
public Vector3 Size = new Vector3 (3, 3, 3);
private int rowLen;
private GameObject[,] allObjects = new GameObject[23, 44];

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    int row = 0; int col = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < map.Length; index++) {
        char c = map [index];
        if (c == '\n') {
            row++;
            col = 0;
        } else {
            GameObject go;
            GameObject whattocreate = null;
            Vector3 p = Vector3.zero;
            if (c == '•') {
                p = new Vector3 (190 + col*Size.x, 0,35 + row*Size.z);
                if (col != 0) {
                    if (map [index - 1] == '•' || map [index - 1] == '_') { whattocreate = wallFloor; Instantiate (wallLeft, p, Quaternion.identity); }
                }
                if (col != 43) {
                    if (map [index + 1] == '•' || map [index + 1] == '_') { whattocreate = wallFloor;Instantiate (wallRight, p, Quaternion.identity);}
                }
                if (row != 0) {
                    if (map [index - 44] == '•' || map [index - 44] == '_') { whattocreate = wallFloor;Instantiate (wallUp, p, Quaternion.identity);}
                }
                if (row != 22) {
                    if (map [index + 44] == '•' || map [index + 44] == '_') { whattocreate = wallFloor;Instantiate (wallDown, p, Quaternion.identity);}
                }
            }
            if (c == ' ') {
                p = new Vector3 (190 + col*Size.x, 0,35 + row*Size.z);
                whattocreate = floor;
                }
            if (c == '_') {
                p = new Vector3 (190 + col * Size.x, 0, 35 + row * Size.z);
                if (map [index - 44] == '•' && map [index + 44] == '•') { whattocreate = doorV; }
                if (map [index - 1] == '•' && map [index + 1] == '•') { whattocreate = doorH;}
            }
            if (whattocreate != null) {
                go = Instantiate (whattocreate, p, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                allObjects [row, col] = go;
            }
            col++;
        }
    }
}
```

This generates a map that looks like this: 
[image: Map]

You can see in the top right the final tile gets messed up and I have no clue why. My teacher didn't know either. (But didn't give much of a try)

Thanks to anyone that can help me with this problem :)

Comment: Add a breakpoint and check is it the first or last tile that goes wrong.

Comment: Change your `for`loop like this: `index < map.Length - 1`

Comment: @Hristo ^ This didn't seem to work but thanks.

Comment: @m.rogalski it would be the last tile